# Is nibbana the only next world in reality?

Tags: nirvana

As in, nibbana is not impermanent, not unsatisfactory. It is still not-self, but in being different with respect to two out of three marks, it satisfies the notion of some fundamentally 'other' world more than any of the heavens in Buddhist literature. Does nibbana make more sense as the 'other world' mentioned in the stock description of right view?

> "And what is the right view with effluents, siding with merit,
>   resulting in acquisitions? 'There is what is given, what is offered,
>   what is sacrificed. There are fruits & results of good & bad actions.
>   There is this world & the next world." MN117

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ud 8.1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.8.01.irel.html) says Nibbana is not a "world" (*loka*) or "other world" (*paraloka*). Any "world" includes suffering ([SN 12.44](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn12.44)). Nibbana is the cessation of the world (*lokanirodhañca*; [AN 4.45](https://suttacentral.net/en/an4.45)).

> *Tasmā have lokavidū sumedho, Lokantagūlokantagū vusitab­rahma­cariyo; Lokassa antaṃ samitāvi ñatvā, Nāsīsatī lokamimaṃ parañcā*
>
> *So, truly, the wise one,  an expert with regard to the world,  a knower of the end of the world,  having fulfilled the holy life,
> calmed,  knowing the worlds’ end,  doesn’t long for this world or
> for any other world.*
>
> [*AN 4.45*](https://suttacentral.net/en/an4.45)